# PowerShell Search look for files in a text file

Tags: powershell

Need to loop through a list of file stored in a .txt file to find the path of each file

```
 files.txt
 example of the file in files.txt > 3030009948_3030009912_df1389947f0fb80d62832122.sasf
```

Using this

```
Get-ChildItem “file_location” -Recurse -Include “*.**” | foreach-object {$_.Fullname} | Out-File c:\files2.txt –width 1024
File Location is a network share Z:
```

Search for each file stored in files.txt export the path of the file in files2.txt
Files will be found on Z: - network share

Comment: I don't understand, are you looking for files `*.mp*` or are you looking for a list of files similar to `3030009948_3030009912_df1389947f0fb80d62832122.sasf`, of which the list is saved in a .txt file?

Comment: so the .sasf are the filenames saved in the .txt need to search for each file listed and display the path on Z:

Comment: Will those files be found on the Z: drive, or are they on the local machine?

Comment: Found on Z: network share

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You kind of have what you need already, so this is fairly simple, you just need to read the text file in and pipe it to your Get-ChildItem in a ForEach loop (I use Select -Expand FullName instead of looping each and selecting the property), then pipe that to Out-File.

```
GC files.txt | %{GCI Z:\$_ -Recurse|Select -Expand FullName} | Out-File Z:\Files2.txt
```

**Edit:** Ok, so you say that didn't work, but I don't know why it wouldn't. It worked fine for me on my machine when I tested it. It may have been slow anyway though since it was pulling a directory listing for a network drive once for each file, so we'll do this differently.

```
$Files = GC files.txt
$DirList = GCI Z:\ -Recurse
$Dirlist | ?{$Files -contains $_.Name} | Select -Expand FullName | Out-File Z:\Files.txt
```

That loads your list of files into an array, then pulls a full directory listing for the Z:\ drive, then filters the directory listing checking each file to see if it's name is in the list of desired files, and expands the FullName property, and saves it to the desired file.

Comment: Seems to not be working display non relevant file                                      Z:\02\10
Z:\02\11
Z:\02\12
Z:\02\13
Z:\02\14
Z:\02\19
Z:\02\20
Z:\02\21
Z:\02\25
Z:\02\26
Z:\02\27
Z:\02\28
Z:\02\10\10
Z:\02\10\11
Z:\02\10\13
Z:\02\10\14
Z:\02\10\15
Z:\02\10\17
Z:\02\10\10\30
Z:\02\10\10\40
Z:\02\10\10\50
Z:\02\10\11\10
Z:\02\10\13\30
Z:\02\10\14\30
Z:\02\10\14\40
Z:\02\10\14\50
Z:\02\10\14\30\1030451778_1030451732_399ea71c3fd244ac9ef0fea9.sasf
Z:\02\10\14\40\1030451835_1030451826_2779c0563bb33b8222f86b01.sasf
none of these are in my files.txt

Comment: I updated my answer. I don't know why that gave you bad results, I did test my first answer and it gave me good results, but the second answer is probably faster for you anyway.

Comment: Didn't give you bad marks just checked it using your second example now